# Ensuring edges of graph obey triangle inequality

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am generating graphs with edges being assigned random weights. How can I guarantee that the weights of edges obey the triangle inequality? I saw a similar question that has been asked but couldn't really follow the answer

Comment: It would make more sense to me to tag this algorithm than python.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far (maybe the program you generate the graph).

Comment: What are your requirements on statistical distribution / independence of these values? A simple solution would be to assign random coordinates to each node & then just make the edge weight the distance between its nodes.

Comment: Could you link to the similar question you found? Maybe we can clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

@Tau is right, there are a lot of ways to solve this problem.

1. Assign random coordinates and take distances using any metric that satisfies the triangle inequality.
2. Assign random weights, test whether the triangle inequality is satisfied, increase the weights of any edges that fail it.
3. Assign random weights, test whether the triangle inequality is satisfied, redo if any edges fail it.

I can come up with more strategies as well.  But the real question is why you are doing this, and whether there are any hidden requirements that make one solution better than another.

Answer (score 0):

In the supplementary material of **The geometric nature of weights in real complex networks** paper, you find a section called *TEST OF THE TRIANGLE INEQUALITY* in which they explain in detail how to perform the test. You can find the paper and the supplementary file from [the author's website](http://complex.ffn.ub.es/%7Embogunya/publications.php). I also agree with @David Conrad that this question belongs to the algorithm tag.